# Razor/MVC 3 Entity Framework Error Regarding Primary Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I'm using VS 2010 with Razor/MVC 3 to create a form where User 1 submits information to a database using RequestQueue Model (this is just a queue table). User 2 then pulls this information, approves it, and the data is sent to the main database via DbRequestForm Model. This model, however, consists of several sub-models (Data_Dictionary, SERVER_DATABASE, and DatabaseRequestInfo) because the submitted data needs to go to three separate tables.

The problems is, whenever I approve the data for submission from RequestQueue to DbRequestForm, I get an error saying there is no primary key for DbRequestForm. However, there is a PK for each sub-model. I have also tried adding [Key] `public int SrvrDB_ID { get; set; }` and other variations to DbRequestForm to no avail.

Initial Model:

```
public class RequestQueue
{
    [Key]
    public int SrvrDB_ID { get; set; }
    public string dbName { get; set; }

    public int InitialSpaceNeeded { get; set; }
    public string ScheduledJobSetup { get; set; }

    public string PII_data { get; set; }
}
```

Encapsulating Model:

```
public class DbRequestForm
{
    public Data_Dictionary Data_Dictionary { get; set; }
    public DatabaseRequestInfo DatabaseRequestInfo { get; set; }
    public SERVER_DATABASE SERVER_DATABASE { get; set; }
}
```

Models based on final three tables:

```
public class Data_Dictionary
{
    [Key]
    public int SrvrDB_ID { get; set; }
    public string PII_data { get; set; }
}

public class SERVER_DATABASE
{
    [Key]
    public int SrvrDB_ID { get; set; }
    public string dbName { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseRequestInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int SrvrDB_ID { get; set; }
    public int InitialSpaceNeeded { get; set; }
    public string ScheduledJobSetup { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas how to avoid this error? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The specific error is '

> System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'DbRequestForm' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>     System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet DbRequestForms is
>   based on type DbRequestForm that has no keys '

Comment: Please provide a trimmed-down example with a model with one or two properties, the actual names (`B` = `SERVER_DATABASE`?), the controller and data access code and the exact exception.

Comment: This is more of an EntityFramework question than an MVC one.

Comment: Haha this is the trimmed down version... I'll try and make it even more concise/specific. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I trimmed it down a little bit and renamed the generic Table A, etc. to their actual names. And sorry, I should have tagged entity-framework initially, I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells that you need to define key for DBRequestForm.
Code First would infer that a property is a primary key if the property is called ‘Id’ or ‘class name Id’. 
In your case you have to add

```
[Key]
public int DBRequestFormId { get; set; }
```

This concrete error won't appear anymore.
here is detailed information how code first works
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx
see the Primary Key section

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Unfortunately I'm still getting that error, but there's some great information in the link you provided and I'm going to keep playing around with it. I'm about done for the day, but I'll report back when I've had a chance to look at this in the next day or two.

Comment: maybe there is another error. if it is so, please post here. if you added to the class DbRequestForm exactly that code that I have posted, there must not be the same error

Comment: Sorry, meant to follow up sooner, just been busy. Anyways..basically right now I'm stuck on the error 'The model backing the 'DbRequestFormContext' context has changed since the database was created' and so on. I spent a very long time yesterday trying to get around this error, but was not successful. I manually deleted the .mdf file, tried to add 'DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges' to Application_Start, and then tried using migration with NuGet. While using the latter I somehow broke everything...rebuilt it all this morning, getting same error. So frustrating. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If your current error is this: "'The model backing the 'DbRequestFormContext' context has changed since the database was created'" then drop database from sql server (if you have no the usefull data in database) and run the program again, it will recreate the database again. there won't be the same error. let me know the next error text :)

Comment: Right now I'm just doing this locally, I'm not actually connected to a sql server (was hoping to get this working first before moving onto the actual servers just to be safe). I have tried deleting the mdf/sdf files located in the App_Data folder. Is that not correct? I'm not sure how else I would delete the table.

Comment: In visual studio -> View -> Server Explorer. look inside, maybe there you can see your db and delete it. try it

Comment: Just tried that again, nothing shows up under Data Connections. Under Servers I see one with numbers in the name (#####-#######), and it has a bunch of stuff in it (Event Logs, Management Classes, Message Queues, Services, etc.) but I don't see anything to do with the DB. And thanks for your patience on this issue, very much appreciated.